# Direct link to full vs. mobile chat

Tags: support, chat, hyperlinks

Is there a direct URL that can be used to link to the full and mobile versions of chat?

The "mobile" link in the bottom does some JavaScript stuff and looks like it makes a POST request to `/mobile/on` and `/mobile/off` first and that seems to control it, but I'd like a direct URL for a userscript I'm working on. Is there a query parameter or a different path or something that can select the chat version?

Comment: Can't you just do the same POST from the userscript?

Comment: @Cai Well then the setting is global. I'd like to not affect other chat windows, ideally. I would have done it that way, though, if there was no other way, but it looks like there is. Plus, while I'm doing this in a script, I was also curious if I could share direct links, too (no reason; but good info to file away).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add [`mobile=1` to the query parameters](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms?mobile=1) (or `0` to trigger the full page on mobile), but the setting doesn't persist. You could potentially combine it with the on/off action if starting on the desired mobile/full page is sufficient